# Use a different shareable config for eslint in a subfolder of a project

Tags: javascript, eslint, eslint-config-airbnb

I have a node 8 project in ES6, that also contains some client-side code in ES5. I'm linting the node code with eslint and using airbnb-base for it.

However, the client-side code is ES5, so I want to use airbnb-base/legacy for it. The problem is that the ES5 client-side code is in a subfolder of the project, which automatically inherits the main eslint configuration (so also the `extends: ["airbnb-base"]`.

Is there a way to specify `extends: ["airbnb-base/legacy"]` for folder below the main config, and not inherit `airbnb-base`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you specify [`root: true`](https://eslint.org/docs/user-guide/configuring#configuration-cascading-and-hierarchy) in your subfolder's `.eslintrc.js`, then you can can then `extends: ["airbnb-base/legacy"]`, and it won't inherit any config from the parent directory.